# How to check the possible values of a column using SQL?

Tags: sql

I wanted to see what are the possible values for a specific column e.g. `col_1`. In python this is just `set(df.col_1.tolist())` but I am not sure how to do it in SQL.

Comment: Unrelated, but have you tried `df.col_1.unique()` in Python? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT DISTINCT col_1 FROM your_table;` should do the job for you.

And you can add ORDER BY col_1 at the end if you want an ordered list.

Comment: @S3DEV . . . `distinct` is *never* a function, not in any database that I know of.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Fair play, thank you.  I've always used it as a function in MySQL - but just reviewed the docs and very definitely not a function, as you say.  Thanks.